# Spring Dependency Injection Example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

i am working on Spring dependency Injection.

I want to calculate area of a rectangle and circle using spring and make use of dependency injection.

Till now i have completed this:

**Interface:**

```
public interface Shape {
   double calculateArea();
}
```

**Circle class**

```
public class Circle implements Shape{

    @Autowired
    public double radius;

    @Override
    public double calculateArea() {
        double area = (Math.PI)*radius*radius;
        return area;
    }

}
```

**Rectangle class:**

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {

    @Autowired
    public double length;

    @Autowired
    public double breadth;

    @Override
    public double calculateArea() {
        double area = length*breadth;
        return area;
    }
}
```

**bean xml:**

```
<bean id="circle" class="org.package.test.Circle">
    <property name="radius" value="12"/>
</bean>
<bean id="rectangle" class="org.package.test.Rectangle">
    <property name="length" value="12"/>
    <property name="breadth" value="10"/>
</bean>

<bean id="geometricalShape" class="org.package.test.GeometricalShape">
    <constructor-arg ref="circle"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="rectangle"/>
</bean>
```

**GeometricalShape.java**

```
private Shape shape;

private Shape shape1;
   /**
    * Inject circle object via Constructor
    */
   public GeometricalShape(Shape shape,Shape shape1) {
      this.shape = shape;
      this.shape1 = shape1;
   }

   public void calculate() {
      shape.calculateArea();
      shape1.calculateArea();
   }
}
```

**Main.Java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

        GeometricalShape bean1=context.getBean("geometricalShape", GeometricalShape.class);
        geometryBean1.calculate();           
    }
}
```

Here i am directly providing the radius/length or breadth as a static value. How can i provide it as a dynamic value (That is any value i want by changing it in Spring?) Is there any better way of doing this using Spring dependency Injection? Any suggestions please?

Comment: You would usually not inject mutable (changing, dynamic) pieces of data using Spring. You are more likely to inject data providers (they don't change, but provide dynamic data) or data processors. Spring's wiring happens on creation of context.

Comment: Of course you can use FactoryBeans to provide values dynamically *at the time of injection*, but this should be used with caution.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to autowire scalar values into your `Circle` and `Rectangle` classes. This will not work. The proper solution is using Spring's **[@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)** annotation which will be detected performed by a BeanPostProcessor and injected for you.

```
<bean
  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="properties">
        <value>
            circle.radius=12
            rectangle.length=12
            rectangle.breadth=10
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then what you can do is:

```
public class Circle implements Shape{

    @Value("#{circle.radius}")
    public double radius;

    @Override
    public double calculateArea() {
        double area = (Math.PI)*radius*radius;
        return area;
    }

}
```

or even in your bean definition you can define it like this

```
<bean id="circle" class="org.package.test.Circle">
    <property name="radius" value="#{circle.radius}"/>
</bean>
```

You can see in my example that `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` has also `locations` property so you can move this value into a file. Also Spring can read it from Environment variable or System properties. I would recommend reading [Spring's reference documentation.](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html)